# Specifying conditions in Rails Query with includes not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I am really stuck in something quite simple. I am unable to specify conditions in my active record query with includes.
Following is my code that states my problem.

```
2.2.1 :072 > visitor = Visitor.includes(:campaign).first
2.2.1 :073 > visitor.campaign.merchant_id
 => 123456
```

Above mentioned case is working well.
Now when I try the following it fails.

```
2.2.1 :076 > visitor = Visitor.includes(:campaign).where("campaign.merchant_id = 123456").references(:campaign).first
ERROR -- : Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'campaign.merchant_id' in 'where clause'
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Just for your info.
Campaign has many visitors
Visitor belongs to a campaign
Campaign has an attribute merchant_id which i am using to specify a condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't your table named `campaigns` not `campaign`?  Rails is just passing the string straight through to SQL, so it tries to find the table `campaign`.  Assuming you're using standard rails pluralization, the table name is wrong in that case.

**Expanded Answer**: Your error is a MySQL error, not from rails.  That means that your ruby code parsed without error, so you need to look one step below rails- i.e. in the database.  From the error message, you can see the problem lives in your SQL `WHERE` clause.  You could take a look at the SQL you're trying to run with

```
Visitor.includes(:campaign).where("campaign.merchant_id = 123456").to_sql
```

which would show something like

```
SELECT * from 'visitors' INNER JOIN campaigns
WHERE campaign.merchant_id = 123456
```

And if you tried to run that SQL at your MySQL prompt, you would get the same "unknown column" error from the database.  The reason is MySQL tries to find a column named `campaign.merchant_id`, which doesn't exist, because the table part (`campaign`) doesn't exist.

If you change your ruby code to `where('campaigns.merchant_id = 123456')` it should work.

**However**, even better is to stay entirely in ruby and use the [syntax to add conditions to joined tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables):

```
Visitor.includes(:campaign).where(:campaigns => {:merchant_id => 123456})
```